# h2o: Flow UI, ROC with drf without fold

Tags: machine-learning, h2o, roc, auc

I managed to plot my ROC with distributed random forest. I noticed that the ROC was plotted with 0 nfold. I'm puzzled how h2o plotted the ROC with 1 set of data. I did not select a validation frame for this experiment. If it is using the same set of dataset to self validate, shouldn't the AUC be 1.0?

Answer (score 1):

Unless the model perfectly fit the training dataset you won't see a perfect score. If you only provide a training dataset and don't use nfolds, then H2O will only use your training data.